# Column/Row operations (insert, delete) are very slow in Excel 2010

Tags: performance, vba, excel, insert, row

I am having great problems with a VBA macro I've written for Excel 2003. It imports some data from other files. The result is that the file size of the Excel file (number of Rows/Cols) increases with every imported file. In Excel 2003 it runs very fast for the first 50 imported files and then it slows down. But with Excel 2010 it takes a considerable amount of time even for small numbers of files. The problem lies in one statement that is executed many times:

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Rows(LastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

This line takes nearly a second in Excel 2010 when the file is becoming larger. When I add a Row manually I am experiencing the same problem.

I do the usual bunch of things to improve performance:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False  
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  
Application.EnableEvents = False  
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False  
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Thanks in advance for your help. I am pretty sure that someone else has already had this problem.

Comment: Can you find a way to not use that row Insert? How are you adding the new information?

Comment: Is `LastRow` really the last row? If so, why insert and not just copy?

Comment: The insert is used because the format of the previous row is copied to the newly inserted row. But I think I'm going to just fill in the data and not care about the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I applied conditional formatting. For every new line that was added to the report a new conditional format rule was created to color a cell in one column that was the same for every row (e.g. the format rule was "if the cell in column A of the current row contains 'enabled' then make the cell green").
In Excel 2003 the conditional formats don't seem to be recalculated if Application.Calculation is set to manual or if the conditional formats are handled differently (I don't know).
Knowing this I manually created a conditional format rule for the whole columns that had to be colored and removed the code to color the single cells from the spreadsheet. Now the thing runs fast in Excel 2010.
I wonder if there is a possibility to file a bug report (disable conditional format recomputing if Application.Calculation is set to manual).

Comment: Weather or not you use conditional formatting there should be a good routine that will insert a row for you if that is truly the only option. you should change the question since there is no way to get this solution from that question. What you really need is a way to keep the formulas from adjusting after EACH insert is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Using Insert is slow because it forces Excel to do a lot of work. Its much faster to just write a large chunk of data directly from a variant to the sheet.
If you want to preserve some formulas at the bottom such as totals then it would be faster to copy the formula block into a variant, write the data to the sheet, adjust the formula and then write it back at the end.
If you have other formulae that reference the sheet where the data is added you could use dynamic range names to refer to the data, or ordinary range names to refer to the total formulae.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, I'll just add the data at the bottom (see comments).

Comment: But the question is still why inserting has become so slow in Excel 2010. It worked perfectly in 2003. I have a related problem where I delete rows and there it's just the same.

Comment: Probably because of the increased numbers of rows and columns: insert and delete imply searching for all formulas so that the references can be adjusted.

Comment: But the sheets contain nearly no formulas and the files were not smaller in Office 2003.

Comment: What I told you about the formulas was not exactly right (see my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but first import all of the data, then add formatting/conditional formatting for a range vs. a new conditional formatting per record.

Answer (score 0):

Using Insert will slow up the process if we have conditional formats. So there are 2 options here.
One to delete the conditional formats before running the insert code. Below code snippiet will help

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions).FormatConditions.Delete
```

Second option is instead of inserting Rows one by one in loop, get the count of rows that needs to be inserted and then execute that in one single line which would drastically reduce the time of single execution. Blow code snippet will help for that

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(rowCount).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Where rowCount is number of Rows to Insert.

Answer (score -1):

Very strange....  Inserting a row was fast.  Then, I sorted a range of rows, and it became excruciatingly slow.  I deleted the row after UsedRange, and it was fine again!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments. You should delete this "answer".